# Where to storage private images in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, wwwroot

Firtsly I use wwwroot to storage images that were uploaded by users and I showed that images like this:

```
<img src="~/Images/ImageName" />
```

But I realize that I can access all the images inside wwwroot by url even if I not logged, and if the image change the browser still showing the first image till I clear cache.

Next I create a carpet in the ContentRootPath to storage my images, calling them throgh a controller using:

```
Stream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_hosting.ContentRootPath, "PrivateFiles\\Images\\Usuarios\\" + imageName),
                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
                    bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
```

and works fine in development but when I publish the project to deploy in SmarterAsp the images aren't showing.

Comment: Here is another way to try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957531/how-to-protect-static-folder-in-asp-net-core-2-1-using-claims-based-authorizatio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already achieve this calling wwwroot images from a controller to authorize, also I add differents names to images everytime are changed to not cached them.